# State callback function being called before Fysom initialization from inside a class

Tags: python

I'm using `Fysom` to create a finite state machine in Python, and I'm seeing one issue which I don't know why it's happening.

I create a `MyClass` class, and inside that class I create a `self.fsm` member which is an instance of `Fysom`.

For some reason, the `fsm` member of my class seems to not exist when the first state of the finite state machine is reached. But when the second state is reached, it does exist.

```python
from fysom import Fysom

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fsm = Fysom({
            'initial': 'start',
            'events': [ { 'src': 'start', 'name': 'go', 'dst': 'end' } ],
            'callbacks': {
                # States callbacks
                'onstart': self.on_start_callback,
                'onend': self.on_end_callback,
                # Events callbacks
                'onbeforego': self.show_event
            }
        })

    def on_start_callback(self, event):
        print "state: start"
        print "self attrs: {}".format(self.__dict__)

    def on_end_callback(self, event):
        print "state: end"
        print "self attrs: {}".format(self.__dict__)

    def show_event(_, event):
        print "event: {}".format(event.event)

def main():
    instance = MyClass()
    instance.fsm.go()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this is the output:

```
state: start
self attrs: {}
event: go
state: end
self attrs: {'fsm': <fysom.Fysom object at 0x7fe948f11510>}
```

Why the `fsm` member of `MyClass` doesn't exists when the initial state (`start`) is reached? Is not supposed to be created and initialized at the class constructor `__init__`?

My guess is that the `on_start_callback` (which is the callback for the initial state of the finite state machine) is called when the `Fysom` instance is being created and before it's assigned to the `fsm` member, therefore it fails when trying to access `self.fsm`. **Is that what actually happens and is that the correct behavior?**

I have found a workaround for that issue by creating an initial state that does nothing (or at least it doesn't access `self` at all) and then from the `main` function I manually trigger the event that transits to the real initial state which does access `self` (at that point is already defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guess is correct and it's the correct behavior. `__init__` is executed in order. Your callback happens when the fsm is created and before it's assigned to `self.fsm`, so `self.__dict__` is still empty.

After you've successfully instantiated and assigned the fsm, you could initialize it within the `__init__`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fsm = Fysom({
            'initial': 'none',
            'events': [
                { 'name': 'initialize', 'src': 'none', 'dst': 'start'},
                { 'src': 'start', 'name': 'go', 'dst': 'end' } ],
            'callbacks': {
                # States callbacks
                'onstart': self.on_start_callback,
                'onend': self.on_end_callback,
                # Events callbacks
                'onbeforego': self.show_event
            }
        })
        self.fsm.initialize()
```

Comment: While correct, this answer is much more convoluted than it needs to be.

Comment: The answer could be little more than this phrase: "while creating the fsm, you have a callback that prints out the object's dictionary before the fsm is made and attached."

Comment: Adding that `self.fsm.initialize()` line causes this error: `AttributeError: 'Fysom' object has no attribute 'initialize'`. What were you trying to achieve by adding that line?

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera i tried to do it without testing it as I don't have the fysom package. when you tried it, did you also add the new event to `'events'`?  (this one, `{ 'name': 'initialize', 'src': 'none', 'dst': 'start'}`)

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera i was working off of this link https://github.com/mriehl/fysom#initialization

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the event, and you forgot to change the initial state. That solution does basically the same as I used as workaround, but I prefer yours. Thanks!